# How to create report (RDLC) with dynamic datasource?

Tags: reporting, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

in my project, i have to show 100+ same report with title, description and list. i want to create one rdlc file and set title, description and list datasource (i can not predefine column numbers and types. it will be defined at runtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem by that example : http://www.gotreportviewer.com/ but should extent this project. because my reports have a title and description than i create subreport and create rdlc file at runtime and set subreport datasource. sory my bad english.